# Remove space between two graphs

Tags: r, plot

Is there a way to attach two graphs, which I obtain with the command`par(mfrow=c(2,1))`, in such a way that the space in between the two plot window is removed? That's something that can easily done with any image editor, but I was guessing if there was a more fair way to do that from command line.

Thanks in advance!

EB

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set the bottom and top margins to zero for each plot then you can do this:

```
> par(mfrow=c(2,1))
> par(mar=c(0,1,1,1))
> plot(1:10)
> par(mar=c(1,1,0,1))
> plot(1:10)
```

producing:

[image]

the `mar` parameter is bottom, left, top, right, and I should have made the left and bottom margins a bit bigger to make room for the axis labelling.

If you do a lot of this sort of "faceting" plot you might be better off using `ggplot`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using base graphics, then look at ?par and in particular the mar and omar parameters.